# Receiving notification additional data on Ionic (ionic native push / phonegap-plugin-push)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic-native, phonegap-plugin-push

We are struggling with Ionic Native push plugin (which is based on phonegap-plugin-push). While we do receive push notifications sent, we cannot process the specific payload that we send so that when the notification is tapped, the app opens in a specific page.

For Android push notifications we use Firebase Cloud Messaging to deliver the notifications, for iOS we are using APNS.

The app opens, but either in the home page or whatever page was open before.

Here is our init push code:

```js
private initPush() {
    this.push.hasPermission()
        .then((res: any) => {
           // just some console logs irrelevant to this question
        });
    const options: PushOptions = {
      android: { clearBadge: true, forceShow: true },
      ios: { alert: 'true', badge: true, sound: 'false', clearBadge: true },
      windows: {}
    };
    const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);
    try {
      pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => this.onNotification(notification));
      pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => this.onRegister(registration));
        pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => this.onError(error));
        this.authorizationService.currentUser.subscribe((nextUser) => this.fullfillPushTokenRegistration());
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Error on registering push methods', e);
    }
  }

  onNotification(notification): void {
      console.info('On Push Notification', JSON.stringify(notification));
      const addData = notification.additionalData;
      this.notificationEventsService.createEvent('push', 'click', addData);
  }
```

The `onNotification` method, which should be fired with the Ionic Native push "notification" event is never called, hence we can't process the additional payload that lets us navigate to the specific page related to the notification.

We're using the following versions:

```
@ionic/core: 4.11.1
@ionic-native/push: 5.15.0
phonegap-plugin-push: 2.3.0
@angular/core: 8.1.2
```

We are aware that this plugin is discontinued and that we should probably switch to OneSignal, but we're trying to avoid this unless it's our last resort, since it would require an additional development.

This is the Kotlin code fragment where we create the notification with the payload, if it helps:

```kotlin
val message = Message.builder().setToken(device.deviceToken)
val fcmNotification: com.google.firebase.messaging.Notification = com.google.firebase.messaging.Notification(
            notification.title, notification.message
        )
message.setNotification(fcmNotification)
message.putData("action", notification.action!!.toString())
message.putData("pendingToViewUserNotifications", pendingToViewUserNotifications.toString())
message.putData("referenced", notification.referenced)
message.putData("notificationId", notification.id.toString())
message.putData("title", notification.title)
message.putData("body", notification.message)
message.putData("badge", pendingToViewUserNotifications.toString())
message.putData("content-available", "1")

when (device.deviceOs!!.toLowerCase()) {
    "android" -> message.setAndroidConfig(AndroidConfig.builder()
        .setTtl(3600 * 1000)
        .setNotification(AndroidNotification.builder()
        .setIcon("stock_ticker_update")
        .setColor("#f45342")
        .build())
        .build())
```

Comment: try `console.log` inside `pushObject.on('notification')` to check are you getting data on not.

Comment: As you can see, the onNotification method does already a console log, without any success at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally managed to fix it... had to set a `content-available: "1"` in the data payload AND a `contentAvailable: true` in the push request body, as well as setting `noCache: "1"`.

Ditched out the Firebase SDK and manually performed the request, now it finally calls `on('notification')`.

You'll want to handle also in your notification callback if `additionalData.foreground` is true, because in foreground the notification event is fired as soon as the notification is displayed, and fired again with foreground to false when tapped.

Here's the sample payload I'm sending to FCM API that worked:

```
{
    "to":"FIREBASE_TOKEN",
    "content_available": true,
    "data": {
        "action": "ACTION(Custom payload data)",
        "referenced": "REFERENCED(Custom payload data)",
        "force-start": "1",
        "content-available": "1",
        "no-cache": "0",
        "notId": "4361c4f5-ae8d-42fa-a863-a04acff2ab7a",
        "title": "TEST"
    }
    "priority":10
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work for you but in my previous app, I had to set different structure for both android and iOS.

Android:

```
      registration_ids : [],
      data: {
        notId: "", // notId on Android needed to be an int and not a string
        title: "",
        body: "",
        soundname: "default",
      }
```

iOS:

```
      registration_ids : [],
      notification:{
        title: "",
        body: "",
        sound: "default",
      },
      data: {
        title: "",
        body: "",
      }
```

OR..

you could go thru this [Android notification data pass](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/pull/2369) where below payload should work for both Android & iOS.

> {
>       "priority" : "high",
>       "notification" : {
>           "title": "Title",
>           "body": "Body",
>           "sound": "default",
>           "click_action": "com.adobe.phonegap.push.background.MESSAGING_EVENT"
>       },
>       "data" : {
>         "more": "data goes here"
>       },
>       "to" : "id"
>   }

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I'm sending the notification using Firebase Cloud messaging for Android, which should already work with the payload I give, I will edit my question anyways to add that part. The other options is an open pull request? I'm not sure if it would work in stable versions

Comment: Finally fixed... here's the bounty for you as a thank you for the effort.

Answer (score -1):

For the past 2 weeks I have been upgrading a cordova 7 app to cordova 12, basically to comply with the Android 12 and 13 requirements regarding local and push notifications, after upgrading cordova and the required plugins, the problem that I had, the push.on "notification" event was not triggering after clicking on the push notification when the app is in the background/killed, what it solved for me was to add the click_action to the payload:

```
"click_action": "com.adobe.phonegap.push.background.MESSAGING_EVENT"
```

I was already setting content-available: "1".