# Ionic 4+ Push Notifications Custom Parameters

Tags: javascript, push-notification, ionic4

I converted my Ionic 3 apps from version 3 to ( 4 or 5)

Tn the previous version I used :

```
notification.additionalData.foreground
```

to receive custom parameters but now this doesn't work anymore.

I have this method :

```
pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => {
}
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot post a comment because id not have enough reputation points. Anyway, you should mention which plug in you are using such as native or one signal ... etc.

Anyhow, see this answer.

[Receiving notification additional data on Ionic (ionic native push / phonegap-plugin-push)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60523549/receiving-notification-additional-data-on-ionic-ionic-native-push-phonegap-pl)